# Reverse Polish Notation mips algorithm

Tags: mips

As a beginner student i have a difficult time with mips language.
Recently, i checked a MIPS reverse polish notation program that i found on the internet from University of Edinburgh and i have few questions to ask.

**The following code isn't mine.It's university of Edinburgh's property**

```
# ======================================================
# Reverse Polish Notation Calculator
# ===================================================================
# RPN calculator in MIPS
#
# Inf2C-CS Coursework 1. Task B
# SOLUTION
#
# Paul Jackson
# 10 Oct 2012

    #==================================================================
    # DATA SEGMENT
    #==================================================================
    .data
                    # // Global variables in memory
                    # int stack[STACK_SIZE] ;
    .align 2        # // Ensure stack array starts on word boundary
stack:  .space 20       # // Allocate STACK_SIZE * 4 byte words for stack
                    # // where STACK_SIZE = 5.
stack_end:

                    # // String constants
prompt: .asciiz "> "    # char* prompt = "> " ;
newline:
    .asciiz "\n"    # char* newline = "\n" ; 

empty:                  # char* empty = "(EMPTY)\n" // Stack empty message
    .asciiz "(EMPTY)\n" 
colonsp:
    .asciiz ": "    # char* colonsp = ": " // For stack print formatting

    #==================================================================
    # TEXT SEGMENT  
    #==================================================================
    .text

    # // Register usage.
    # //
    # int* stackp ;   // $s0.  Stack pointer
    # int* stack  ;   // $s1.  &stack[0] - Start address of stack 
    # int* stack_end ;// $s2.  &stack[STACK_SIZE] - First address after
    #                 //                            end of stack
    # int  c          // $s3.  Input character (coerced to int)

    # int  s4 // $s4 Temporary var preserved across function calls
    # int  s5 // $s5 Temporary var preserved across function calls

    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    # PUSH FUNCTION
    #------------------------------------------------------------------
                          # void push (int i) 
                          # i in $a0
push:                         # {
                          #     if (stackp < stack_end) 
    slt  $t1, $s0, $s2    #         // $t1 = stackp < stack_end
    beqz $t1, push_end    #         // b push_end if $t1 == 0
                          #     {
    sw   $a0, 0($s0)      #         *stackp = i ;
    addi $s0, $s0, 4      #         ++stackp ;
                          #     }
push_end:       
    jr $ra                #     return ;
                          # }


    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    # POP FUNCTION
    #------------------------------------------------------------------
                            # int pop() {

pop:                            #     if (stack < stackp) 
    slt  $t1, $s1, $s0      #         // $t1 = stack < stackp
    beqz  $t1, pop1         #         // branch to pop1 if $t1 == 0
                            #     {
    addi $s0, $s0, -4       #         stackp-- ;
                            #         return *stackp ;
    lw   $v0, 0($s0)        #         // $v0 = *stackp
    jr   $ra                #         // return $v0

                            #     } else {
                            #         return 0 ;
pop1:   li   $v0, 0             #         // $v0 = 0
    jr $ra                  #         // return $v0
                            # }


    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    # MAIN BODY
    #------------------------------------------------------------------
main:
    # Initialisation of registers holding constant values

    la  $s1, stack            # // $s1 = &stack[0];
    la  $s2, stack_end        # // $s2 = &stack[STACK_SIZE];

    # Initialisation of registers for main program variable
    move $s0, $s1             # stackp = stack ;

    li $v0, 4                 # print_string("> ")
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall

    #- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    # READ LOOP
    #- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

mainloop:                         # while (1) {


    li $v0, 12                #    c = read_char()
    syscall                 
    move $s3, $v0           

    #- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    # CASE SWITCH ON INPUT CHAR
    #- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

maincase1:  # TEST FOR NEWLINE

    li  $t2, 0x0a             #    if (c == '\n') 
    beq $s3, $t2, print_stack #        break ;

maincase2:  # TEST FOR ENTER NEW NUMBER

    li  $t2, 'e'              #    if (c == 'e')
    bne $s3, $t2, maincase3
                              #    {
    move $a0, $zero           #       push(0) ;
    jal push
    j maincases_end           #    } else


maincase3:      
    # TEST FOR DIGIT
                              # if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') 

    li   $t1, '0'             # // $t1 = '0'
    slt  $t2, $s3, $t1        # // $t2 = c < '0'
    bnez $t2, maincase4       # // Skip case if c < '0'

    li   $t2, '9'             # // $t2 = '9'
    slt  $t3, $t2, $s3        # // $t3 = '9' < c
    bnez $t3, maincase4       # // Skip case if '9' < c
                              # {

                            #    push (10 * pop() + (c - '0'));

    sub $s4, $s3, $t1       #    // $s4 = c - '0'
    jal pop                 #    // $v0 = pop()
    sll $t2, $v0, 1         
    sll $t3, $v0, 3
    add $t3, $t2, $t3       #    // $t3 = 10 * $v0
    add $t3, $t3, $s4       #    // $t3 = $t3 + (c - '0')
    move $a0, $t3
    jal push                #    // push $t3

                            # }
    j maincases_end         # else

maincase4:  # TEST FOR NEGATE

    li  $t2, 'n'            # if (c == 'n') 
    bne $s3, $t2, maincase5
                            # {
                            #    push(-pop());
    jal pop
    sub $a0, $zero, $v0
    jal push
    j maincases_end         # } else 

maincase5:  # TEST FOR + OPERATION

    li  $t2, '+'            # if (c == '+')
    bne $s3, $t2, maincase6
                            # {
                            #    push(pop() + pop());
    jal pop                 #    // $s4 = pop()
    move $s4, $v0
    jal pop                 #    // $v0 = pop()
    add  $a0, $s4, $v0      #    // $a0 = pop() + pop()
    jal push
    j maincases_end         # } else 

maincase6:  # TEST FOR - OPERATION

    li  $t2, '-'            # if (c == '-')
    bne $s3, $t2, maincase7
                            # {
                            #    int arg2 = pop(); // 2nd arg for -
    jal pop                 #    // $s4 = pop()  
    move $s4, $v0
                            #    int arg1 = pop(); // 1st arg for -
    jal pop                 #    // $v0 = pop()

                            #    push(arg1 - arg2);
    sub  $a0, $v0, $s4      #    // $a0 = arg1 - arg2
    jal push                #    // push($a0)

    j maincases_end         # } else 

maincase7:  # TEST FOR * OPERATION

    li  $t2, '*'            # if (c == '*')
    bne $s3, $t2, maincases_end
                            # {
                            #    push(pop() * pop());
    jal pop                 #    // $s4 = pop()
    move $s4, $v0
    jal pop                 #    // $v0 = pop()
    mul  $a0, $s4, $v0      #    // $a0 = pop() * pop()
    jal push                #    // push($a0)
                            # }        

maincases_end:
    j mainloop

    #- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    # PRINT_STACK 
    #- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

print_stack:
    li    $v0, 4            #    print_string("\n") ;
    la    $a0, newline
    syscall

                            #    // This test for the stack being
                            #    // empty was not required in the     submitted
                            #    // solutions.  Indeed the print code
                            #    // in the else case below functions
                            #    // correctly also when stack == stackp.

    bne  $s1, $s0, print1   #    if (stack == stackp) {

    # Uncomment following code to print a message on the stack being empty
    # 
    # li $v0, 4               #       print_string("EMPTY\n")
    # la $a0, empty
    # syscall

    j print_end
print1:                         #    else {
                            #       int * pp; // Use $s4 for pp (print ptr)
    move $s4, $s1           #       pp = stack ;

print2: beq  $s4, $s0, print_end#       while (pp != stackp) {

    li   $v0, 1             #          print_int(pp - stack) ;
    sub  $a0, $s4, $s1      # 
    srl  $a0, $a0, 2        # 
    syscall

    li    $v0, 4            #          print_string(": ") ;
    la    $a0, colonsp
    syscall

    li    $v0, 1            #          print_int(*pp) ;
    lw    $a0, 0($s4)
    syscall

    li    $v0, 4            #          print_string("\n") ;
    la    $a0, newline
    syscall

    add $s4, $s4, 4         #          pp++ ;
    j print2
                            #       }
                            #    }
print_end:

    li $v0, 10      # exit()#    exit() ;
    syscall

    #----------------------------------------------------------------
    # END OF CODE
    #----------------------------------------------------------------
```

**I have the following questions**

Why `stack_end:` label is empty ,while the program works?

Why `move $a0, $zero` ? Why do i have to `push(0)` instead of `push(character)` ?

I cant understand the concept of `push (10 * pop() + (c - '0'));` .Why do i need all those operations rather than simply push,pop to the stack .

I'm a little confused, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be helpful to you, but this program doesn't work correctly in its state. The code is incorrect if we wish to use Reverse Polish Notation. But, I'll try answering anyway.

Stack_end basically works as a null address, it does not have anything inside it, the programmer wants to use it in order to find the first position after the end of the stack.

We push(0) each time we encounter a number. If you are thinking in terms of high level languages it doesn't make sense, but in mips we do move $a0, $zero, which means that we make way for the next number that we input. So we basically "shift" the elements in the stack upward and the new 0 element in the first position will be replaced by our input.

Lastly, the line push (10 * pop() + (c - '0')) makes sense again only in assembly. Let's start from "(c - '0')". This means that your character will be subtracted by the character '0' in its ASCII equivalent number. It would be the same if you would subtract by 48. 
e.g. Say your char is 9 which in ASCII is 57. So, 57 - 48 = 9.

As for the line (10 * pop())  is to keep track of the actual number. Basically, mips can't use a toInt() method it reads each character individually. e.g.
Say, we input 32 and we have a variable x =0.

```
Step 1: In ASCII 51(3) - 48 = 3;
Step 2: x * 10 =0
Step 3: x + 3 = 3
Step 4: In ASCII 50(2) -48 = 2
Step 5: x *10 = 30
Step 6: x + 2 = 32
```

There you go. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It was very useful. I'm a cs undergraduate at AUEB ,too ! Seems we're the only and the crazy ones, studying such things ...